# Matlab group delay not corresponding to reality

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, infinite-impulse-response, group-delay

I studying effects of digital filters group delay (IIR). In Matlab there is a function grpdelay which allows for particular frequency get a value of delay in samples

But after filter applying and comparing of pictures there are diffent results. In rude words if I expect 50 samples delay under grpdelay analysis, in fact I see 100 samples, If I expect 30, I see 70 and so on. What I doing wrong? I use simple sin processed gauss window for example

```
clear;
close all;




t = 0:0.008:600;

x = sin( 2 * pi * t * 1.3 ) .* gausswin(length(t) )';
x = [ zeros(1, 1000) x zeros(1, 1000) ];


fs = 125;
fc_low = 0.5;
fc_high = 3;
order = 4;

[b,a] = butter(order, [ fc_low/(fs/2), fc_high/(fs/2) ] );          
y = filter(b, a, x);


plot(x)

hold on;

plot(y)

legend('orig', 'filtered')


figure;

grpdelay(b, a, 512, fs);
```

below there is example of theoretical and model misfitting

[image]

[image]

So, the result is that Matlab function `grpdelay` gives not accurate results or I have errors in calculation/interpretation ?

Comment: The likelihood that a well established MATLAB function is wrong is extremely low, so chances are it's your code or interpretation. Please post your actual code you used to make the graphs. What you currently have in your are  just a few fragments.

Comment: Thanks! I posted whole code

Comment: Your picture suggests you have misunderstood group delay. You are apparently measuring phase delay.

Comment: I don't think so. In Openheim book, chapter 5 there are the similar example and understanding of group delay as I did

Comment: You should have a look here [Phase/Group-Delay](https://dspillustrations.com/pages/posts/misc/group-delay-and-phase-delay-example.html).

Comment: Thanks, very interesting explanation. You could make extended answer to the post, it would be helpful for many others I guess

Comment: I checked, phasedelay gives correct answer. So, yes it was misunderstanding between group and phase delay from me. Thanks, guys